# What are some good ways to manage a changelog using Git?

Tags: git, github, changelog

I've been using Git for a while now, and I recently started using it to tag my releases so that I could more easily keep track of changes and be able to see which version each of our clients is running (unfortunately the code currently mandates that each client have their own copy of the PHP site; I'm changing this, but it's slow-going).

In any case, we're starting to build some momentum, and I thought it would be really good to be able to show people what has changed since the last release. The problem is, I haven't been maintaining a changelog, because I don't have a good idea of how to go about it. For this particular time, I can run through the log and manually create one, but that will get tiring very quickly.

I tried googling "git changelog" and "git manage changelog", but I didn't find anything that really talked about the workflow of code changes and how that coincides with the changelog. We're currently following [Rein Henrichs' development workflow](http://reinh.com/blog/2009/03/02/a-git-workflow-for-agile-teams.html) and I would love something that went along with that.

Is there a standard approach that I am missing, or is this an area where everybody does their own thing?

Comment: This questions may just need to be changed to "How Can I automate my changelog?" Which is how I would have chosen to answer the op with links to where and how to do this from single dev to big team projects. Now that I automate that process I only look to improve it and never worry about the CHANGELOG, since it should coincide with the Git history.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

This was in 2015, but for the sake of future searchers, it's now possible to generate gorgeous logs with:

```
git log --oneline --decorate
```

Or, if you want it even prettier (with color for the terminal):

```
git log --oneline --decorate --color
```

Piping that output to *ChangeLog* is what I currently use in all my projects, and it's simply amazing.

Comment: Another useful tag is `--graph`, which visually shows you which branches the commits are on.

Comment: @Eruant I find this form to be more appropriate for a changelog, specifically. Since it does exactly that. Graph should be used more by users to find specific things.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using gift log diffs as a CHANGELOG: http://keepachangelog.com

Comment: @OlivierLacan in this case, it gives the revisions numbers (so one can revert to them) and the commit messages (which in theory should effectively be a changelog)

Comment: copying ``git log`` output to changelog has no sense. You need to do a filtering and editing work to have a readable changelog, otherwise, why would you even need a changelog ? I think you can automate the generation of a changelog but please don't do raw copy of ``git log`` !

Comment: `git log`  is readable, people upvoting here have shown. Moreover it's not raw, `--oneline` and `--decorate` are options. It makes perfect sense to use it for software that has releases, where people download a tarball that does not include the .git directory and `git log` is thus unavailable. Please be objective with criticism.

Comment: The problem with this is that, even assuming that every contributor to your project writes clear and readable commit messages, you'll still be generating a "changelog" containing TONS of noise. Changelogs should be written with the goal of explaining to the *users* of your project the *notable* changes *relevant to them* that occurred between releases, whereas commit messages should be focused on explaining to *developers* what improvements your commit makes *to the code*. Sometimes there's overlap there, but not always.

Comment: Or, to make that a bit more concrete, this method will create a "change log" containing lots of entries like "Fixed spelling of fooMethod in ZModule" and "Refactor XModule to use new version of XYLibarary". Your users *don't care* about that. They want to know what changes were made from *their* perspective as users, not *your* perspective as a developer. And that's even ignoring stuff like "Merge PR #123 from xdev/foo" and "Opps, fixed newFeature so it actually works" type things that are likely to exist in any real-world repo.

Comment: Also, even commits that are relevant to a change log probably aren't phrased in a way that users can easily understand. E.g. "Fix YModule to correctly foo the bar" vs "Fix bug causing incorrect layout of blah blah for some users". git log entries *aren't* a viable substitute for a changelog. I guess answers like this are to be expected given the way the question was phrased though...

Comment: @OlivierLacan what’s described in keepachangelog.com is a NEWS file. But instead of saying “there’s the GNU standard, let’s build on it”, the site re-invents the next standard which contradicts the GNU standard (that requires a very strict format for ChangeLog files, focussing on developers, but has a loose format for NEWS which could have easily been used as a base for keepachangelog.com).

Comment: Just to add to this conversation, as the OP I guess I should have stated that I was looking for a _starting point_ for managing the changelog. Something that I could go through and edit out to make it more human readable, but something where I could easily see all of the changes. This method worked great for me because I keep fairly good commit messages, and I can obviously change or edit out the ones I don't care to include.

Answer (score 68):

You can use some flavor of `git log` to help you out:

```
git log --pretty=%s                 # Only prints the subject
```

If you name your branches nicely, so that a merge to master shows up as something like "Merged branch feature-foobar", you can shorten things by only showing that message, and not all the little commits that you merged, which together form the feature:

```
git log --pretty=%s --first-parent  # Only follow the first parent of merges
```

You might be able to augment this with a script of your own, which could do things like strip out the "Merged branch" bits, normalize formatting, etc. At some point you have to write it yourself though, of course.

Then you could create a new section for the changelog once per version:

```
git log [opts] vX.X.X..vX.X.Y | helper-script > changelogs/X.X.Y
```

And commit that in your version release commit.

If your problem is that those commit subjects aren't anything like what you'd want to put in a changelog, you pretty much have two options: keep doing everything manually (and try to keep up with it more regularly instead of playing catch-up at release time), or fix up your commit message style.

One option, if the subjects aren't going to do it for you, would be to place lines like "change: added feature foobar" in the bodies of your commit messages, so that later you could do something like `git log --pretty=%B | grep ^change:` to grab only those super-important bits of the messages.

I'm not entirely sure how much more than that Git could really help you create your changelogs. Maybe I've misinterpreted what you mean by "manage"?

Answer (score 67):

**TL;DR:** You might want to check [gitchangelog's own changelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gitchangelog#changelog) or the [ASCII output](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gitchangelog#sample) that generated the previous.

If you want to generate a changelog from your Git history, you'll probably have to consider:

- the **output format**. (Pure custom ASCII, [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) changelog type, [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), etc.)
- some **commit filtering** (you probably don't want to see all the typos or cosmetic changes getting in your changelog)
- some **commit text wrangling** before being included in the changelog. (Ensuring normalization of messages as having a first letter uppercase or a final dot, but it could be removing some special markup in the summary also.)
- is your **Git history compatible**?. Merging and tagging is not always so easily supported by most of the tools. It depends on how you manage your history.

Optionally, you might want some categorization (new things, changes, bugfixes, etc.).

With all this in mind, I created and used [gitchangelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gitchangelog). It's meant to leverage a **Git commit message convention** to achieve all of the previous goals.

Having a commit message convention is mandatory to create a nice changelog (with or without using `gitchangelog`).

**Commit message convention**

The following are suggestions to what might be useful to think about adding in your commit messages.

You might want to separate roughly your commits into big sections:

- by intent (for example: new, fix, change, etc.)
- by object (for example: doc, packaging, code, etc.)
- by audience (for example: dev, tester, users, etc.)

Additionally, you could want to tag some commits:

- as "minor" commits that shouldn't get outputted to your changelog (cosmetic changes, a small typo in comments, etc.)
- as "refactor" if you don't really have any significant feature changes. Thus this should not also be part of the changelog displayed to final user for instance, but it might be of some interest if you have a developer changelog.
- you could tag also with "API" to mark API changes or new API stuff...
- ...etc...

Try to write your commit message by targeting users (functionality) as often as you can.

**Example**

This is the standard `git log --oneline` to show how this information could be stored::

```
* 5a39f73 fix: encoding issues with non-ASCII characters.
* a60d77a new: pkg: added ``.travis.yml`` for automated tests.
* 57129ba new: much greater performance on big repository by issuing only one shell command for all the commits. (fixes #7)
* 6b4b267 chg: dev: refactored out the formatting characters from Git.
* 197b069 new: dev: reverse ``natural`` order to get reverse chronological order by default. !refactor
* 6b891bc new: add UTF-8 encoding declaration !minor
```

So if you've noticed, the format I chose is:

```
{new|chg|fix}: [{dev|pkg}:] COMMIT_MESSAGE [!{minor|refactor} ... ]
```

To see an actual output result, you could look at the end of the [PyPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Package_Index) page of [gitchangelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gitchangelog).

To see a full documentation of my commit message convention, you can see the reference file [gitchangelog.rc.reference](https://github.com/vaab/gitchangelog/blob/master/src/gitchangelog/gitchangelog.rc.reference).

**How to generate an exquisite changelog from this**

Then, it's quite easy to make a complete changelog. You could make your own script quite quickly, or use `gitchangelog`.

`gitchangelog` will generate a full changelog (with sectioning support as `New`, `Fix`...) and is reasonably configurable to your own committing conventions. It supports any type of output thanks to templating through `Mustache`, `Mako templating`, and has a default legacy engine written in raw Python; all current three engines have examples of how to use them and can output changelogs as the one displayed on the PyPI page of *gitchangelog*.

I'm sure you know that there are plenty of other `git log` to `changelog` tools out there also.

<sub>**DISCLAIMER:** I'm the author of [gitchangelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gitchangelog) of which I'll be speaking in the following.</sub>

Answer (score 30):

A more to-the-point changelog:

```
git log --since=1/11/2011 --until=28/11/2011 --no-merges --format=%B
```

Comment: This kinda does it: I would add other parameters to `--format`, as explained in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats

Answer (score 25):

The [`gitlog-to-changelog`](http://git.sv.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob_plain;f=build-aux/gitlog-to-changelog) script comes in handy to generate a GNU-style `ChangeLog`.

As shown by `gitlog-to-changelog --help`, you may select the commits used to generate a `ChangeLog` file using either the option `--since`:

```
gitlog-to-changelog --since=2008-01-01 > ChangeLog
```

or by passing additional arguments after `--`, which will be passed to `git-log` (called internally by `gitlog-to-changelog`):

```
gitlog-to-changelog -- -n 5 foo > last-5-commits-to-branch-foo
```

For instance, I am using the following rule in the top-level `Makefile.am` of one of my projects:

```
.PHONY: update-ChangeLog
update-ChangeLog:
    if test -d $(srcdir)/.git; then                         \
       $(srcdir)/build-aux/gitlog-to-changelog              \
          --format='%s%n%n%b%n' --no-cluster                \
          --strip-tab --strip-cherry-pick                   \
          -- $$(cat $(srcdir)/.last-cl-gen)..               \
        >ChangeLog.tmp                                      \
      && git rev-list -n 1 HEAD >.last-cl-gen.tmp           \
      && (echo; cat $(srcdir)/ChangeLog) >>ChangeLog.tmp    \
      && mv -f ChangeLog.tmp $(srcdir)/ChangeLog            \
      && mv -f .last-cl-gen.tmp $(srcdir)/.last-cl-gen      \
      && rm -f ChangeLog.tmp;                               \
    fi

EXTRA_DIST += .last-cl-gen
```

This rule is used at release time to update `ChangeLog` with the latest not-yet-recorded commit messages.  The file `.last-cl-gen` contains the SHA-1 identifier of the latest commit recorded in `ChangeLog` and is stored in the Git repository.  `ChangeLog` is also recorded in the repository, so that it can be edited (e.g. to correct typos) without altering the commit messages.

Comment: The GCC mklog script may also be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31606865/895245

Answer (score 24):

Since creating a tag per version is the best practice, you may want to partition your changelog per version. In that case, this command could help you:

```
git log YOUR_LAST_VERSION_TAG..HEAD --no-merges --format=%B
```

Answer (score 11):

I also made a library for this. It is fully configurable with a [Mustache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustache_%28template_system%29) template. That can:

- Be stored to a file, like [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/tree/screenshots/src/test/resources/assertions).
- Be posted to [MediaWiki](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/blob/screenshots/sandbox/example_mediawiki.png)
- Or just be printed to standard output

I also made:

- A [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-gradle-plugin)
- A [Maven plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-maven-plugin)
- A [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Changelog+Plugin)
- A [Bitbucket Server plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-bitbucket-plugin)
- A [command line tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-changelog-command-line)

More details are on GitHub: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib

From the command line:

```
npx git-changelog-command-line -std -tec "
# Changelog

Changelog for {{ownerName}} {{repoName}}.

{{#tags}}
## {{name}}
 {{#issues}}
  {{#hasIssue}}
   {{#hasLink}}
### {{name}} [{{issue}}]({{link}}) {{title}} {{#hasIssueType}} *{{issueType}}* {{/hasIssueType}} {{#hasLabels}} {{#labels}} *{{.}}* {{/labels}} {{/hasLabels}}
   {{/hasLink}}
   {{^hasLink}}
### {{name}} {{issue}} {{title}} {{#hasIssueType}} *{{issueType}}* {{/hasIssueType}} {{#hasLabels}} {{#labels}} *{{.}}* {{/labels}} {{/hasLabels}}
   {{/hasLink}}
  {{/hasIssue}}
  {{^hasIssue}}
### {{name}}
  {{/hasIssue}}

  {{#commits}}
**{{{messageTitle}}}**

{{#messageBodyItems}}
 * {{.}}
{{/messageBodyItems}}

[{{hash}}](https://github.com/{{ownerName}}/{{repoName}}/commit/{{hash}}) {{authorName}} *{{commitTime}}*

  {{/commits}}

 {{/issues}}
{{/tags}}
"
```

Or in Jenkins:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for the chaneglog to simply be a clickable-link within Github?

Answer (score 4):

**GNU style changelog**

For a [GNU style changelog](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Style-of-Change-Logs.html#Style-of-Change-Logs), I've cooked the function:

```
gnuc() {
  {
    printf "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")  John Doe  <john.doe@gmail.com>\n\n"
    git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | sed 's/^/\t* /'
  } | tee /dev/tty | xsel -b
}
```

With this:

- I commit my changes periodically to backup and rebase them before doing the final edit to the ChangeLog
- then run: `gnuc`

and now my clipboard contains something like:

```
2015-07-24  John Doe  <john.doe@gmail.com>

        * gdb/python/py-linetable.c (): .
        * gdb/python/py-symtab.c (): .
```

Then I use the clipboard as a starting point to update the ChangeLog.

It is not perfect (e.g., files should be relative to their ChangeLog path, so `python/py-symtab.c` without `gdb/` since I will edit the `gdb/ChangeLog`), but it is a good starting point.

More advanced scripts:

- [git-gnu-changelog](https://github.com/tromey/git-gnu-changelog) by Tromey, a GDB maintainer
- GCC's [contrib/mklog](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/24882f081964f262ee887bf6d3dde155f4f612aa/contrib/mklog)
- [gcc/contrib/mklog](https://github.com/davidmalcolm/gcc-refactoring-scripts/blob/1fc7fe038bffbb2b48d0a7a300625639f01aefa1/generate-changelog.py)

I have to agree with Tromey though: duplicating Git commit data in the ChangeLog is useless.

If you are going to make a changelog, make it a good *summary* of what is going on, possibly as specified at [Keep a Changelog](http://keepachangelog.com/).

Answer (score 3):

```
git log --oneline --no-merges `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`..HEAD | cut -c 9- | sort
```

Is what I like to use. It gets all commits since the last tag. `cut` gets rid of the commit hash. If you use ticket numbers at the beginning of your commit messages, they are grouped with `sort`. Sorting also helps if you prefix certain commits with `fix`, `typo`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [bithavoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12496121/419348), the following lists the *last tag* until `HEAD`. But I hope to list the logs between two tags.

```
// Two or three dots between `YOUR_LAST_VERSION_TAG` and `HEAD`
git log YOUR_LAST_VERSION_TAG..HEAD --no-merges --format=%B
```

List logs between two tags:

```
// Two or three dots between two tags
git log FROM_TAG...TO_TAG
```

For example, this will list logs from `v1.0.0` to `v1.0.1`:

```
git log v1.0.0...v1.0.1 --oneline --decorate
```

---

Answer (score 3):

I let the [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server pipe the following into a file named `CHANGELOG` for each new release with the date set in the release-filename:

```
git log --graph --all --date=relative --pretty=format:"%x09 %ad %d %s (%aN)"
```