# Do I need to create a changelog file with Git?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git and I am wondering if I need to create a changelog file manually, or if Git keeps track of the changes (I'm using GitHub).

Comment: you have history in git

Comment: OK, so I don't need to add a changelog file?

Comment: if git log is enough for you

Answer (score 2):

Git keeps track of the whole history, yes, that’s the purpose of it. You can always access the commit log using `git log`, or see it for example on GitHub when you have pushed your repository there.

However, those logs will only show you the commits you made, usually being very developer-centric and specific to the implementation. So for public changelogs, you might still want to maintain a user-friendly list of changes.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is for a version control to provide a good tracking of the changes through the revisions and their commit messages.

That being said, you can also generate an extra changelog file from your commits.
See for instance "[Generate your changelogs with Git log](https://coderwall.com/p/5cv5lg)".

> `git log v2.1.0...v2.1.1 --pretty=format:'<li> <a href="http://github.com/jerel/<project>/commit/%H">view commit &bull;</a> %s</li> ' --reverse | grep "#changelog"`

- "[Good ways to manage a changelog using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3523534/6309)"
- python script "[gitchangelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gitchangelog)"