# How to get 'git diff' to only show commit messages

Tags: git

How do I use `git diff` to only show commit messages?

I just want the message of the commit, not the name of the files. I am trying to get a change log in Git.

Comment: Use git log instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
git log --oneline -n 10
```

It will print out the last *n* (10) commits on single lines. Just the commit messages.

You can also combine it with other log parameters, like:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate -n 10
```

Comment: does that work with submodules too? I want to get the submodules changes too

Comment: Sub-modules are basically git repository inside root git repository so you will have to do it inside the folder. you can always write script or alias to do it for you.

Comment: can't I use git diff to show the sub module changes?

Comment: for example:
`git submodule foreach git log --oneline ...`. The for each will loop on all of your submodules.

Answer (score 17):

You could try `git log`, thus,

```
git log commitA...commitB
```

The triple dot notation '...' gives you just the commit messages for all the commits that are reachable from commitA or commitB, but not from both - i.e., the diff between commitA and commitB.

You can easily strip down to just the commit message with something like:

```
git log --pretty=%B commitA...commitB
```

Some examples

```
# Show a log of all commits in either the development branch or master branch since they diverged.
git log --pretty=%B development...master
```

```
# Ahow a log of all commits made to either commit b8c9577  or commit 92b15da, but not to both.
git log --pretty=%B b8c9577...92b15da
```

```
# Show a log for all commits unique to either the local branch master or local version of the origin's master branch.
git co master
git log --pretty=%B master...origin/master
```

```
# Show a log for all commits unique to either the local HEAD or local version of the origin's master branch.
git co master
# Hack, hack
git log --pretty=%B HEAD...origin/master
```

Comment: May be master...development not development..master

Comment: `%B` stands for `raw body (unwrapped subject and body)`. I think that the usage of the `%s subject` is better.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [Simon Clewer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546070/346913) answer:

```
git log master..dev --no-merges --pretty='format:%cs %s'
```

It prints only subjects of commits between master and development branches (without merge commits). Something like this:

```
2020-12-31 Hot fix
2020-12-30 Change some stuff
2020-12-29 Add the feature
```

Changes between local and remote branches:

```
git log HEAD..origin --no-merges --pretty='format:%cs %s'
```

See also *[What are some good ways to manage a changelog using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523534/good-ways-to-manage-a-changelog-using-git)*.

Answer (score 3):

```
git log --pretty=%B
```

will show you the last commit messages.

In case you want to limit the number of commit messages shown by a number, *N*, you can do this by providing an additionally `-N`, e.g.,

```
git log -3 --pretty=%B
```

for the last three commit messages.

Comment: The question was about `git diff`, not `git log`.

Comment: @EntangledLoops - the question seems mainly about "to only show commit messages" for which certain tools seem better than others. But feel free to offer a solution with `git diff`.