# Git Environment Variables within Managed Code

Tags: git

Is there an option that would allow me to place a variable place holder to a git environment variable and upon committing, have that variable be populated with the information within it?

I have an XML file that I have appended my changes too, while providing a comment for visual satisfaction for those who dont use Git and review my files. I want to append the date of the commit from GIT into that variable place holder in the document.

```
<root>
    <!--CR **{git_commit_date}**: Added a root.-->
</root>
```

Comment: I don't *think* git offers that sort of option, but I could be wrong. Your use case sounds like a changelog tho, and there does exist good automation for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523534/good-ways-to-manage-a-changelog-using-git#22492425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

What you are after is traditionally (since
[SCCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System)
or may be even older)
is called "keyword expansion" — as it was used to expand special
placeholders such as `$Id$` by some meta-information from the most recent
commit created by a VCS.

Git explicitly refuses to support this out of the box
but provides means to do that with the help of external tools.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion) is a gentle introduction to the topic,
and [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes/) is the manual.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I am after.